# how to make python perform a command after open cv detected a face?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, raspberry-pi3, robotics

I am building a robot. Pretty much all my code has been copied from other people's projects on tutorials.

I'm using a Raspberry Pi camera to detect faces, and I have this electric Nerf gun, that I want to fire, ONLY after opencv detects a face. Right now, my code fires the Nerf gun no matter if a face is detected or not. Please tell me what I have done wrong? I think the problem is in the `if len(faces) > 0` area. Here is all my code.

### program 1, called cbcnn.py

```
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

def init():
    gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
    gpio.setup(22, gpio.OUT)

def fire(tf):
    init()
    gpio.output(22, True)
    time.sleep(tf)
    gpio.cleanup()

print 'fire'
fire(3)
```

---

program 2, called cbfd2.py

---

```
import io
import picamera
import cv2
import numpy
from cbcnn import fire

#Create a memory stream so photos doesn't need to be saved in a file
stream = io.BytesIO()

#Get the picture (low resolution, so it should be quite fast)
#Here you can also specify other parameters (e.g.:rotate the image)
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (320, 240)
    camera.vflip = True
    camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')

#Convert the picture into a numpy array
buff = numpy.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=numpy.uint8)

#Now creates an OpenCV image
image = cv2.imdecode(buff, 1)

#Load a cascade file for detecting faces 
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/cbot/faces.xml  /haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

#Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Look for faces in the image using the loaded cascade file
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)

print "Found "+str(len(faces))+" face(s)"

if len(faces) > 0:
    ("fire")

#Draw a rectangle around every found face
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

#Save the result image
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',image)
```

Comment: Oh no.  You're not getting away with an off-topic question just because I desperately want a nerf aimbotting robot to be something that exists.  Please look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: I don't understand what I did wrong on my post? Please clarify.

Comment: Nope.  Did you read the links?  There's no specific programming question here, and no way to replicate the error, or even much indication of what the specific error is ("doesn't shoot faces," while hilarious, is not a proper error trace.)

Comment: @Ironchop read the MCVE link that Daniel provided. The idea is that if you have a problem, don't give us a lot of useless information that may or may not be related to the problem. First of all, discover what `faces` contains. And then ask with that as a starting point. Presumably, we don't need all the PiCamera stuff or the CV stack.

Comment: Oh. I thought the entire purpose of this website was to get solutions to programming problems. I guess I don't understand the purpose of this website.

Comment: It *is* a Question & Answer site, but answers are only ever as good as the questions.  I actually really *do* want to help you, but there's nothing for me to even get started with here.

Comment: I don't know what else I can give you.

Answer (score 1):

It fires because you have a `fire(3)` right after you defined the `fire(tf)` function. And the command below only creates a tuple with 1 string value: `("fire")`. It doesn't call the fire function.

```
if len(faces) > 0:
    ("fire")
```

If you want to fire only when faces are detected, move that `fire(3)` under this IF and remove it from the top.

BTW you're importing another thing here: `from cbcnn import fire` with the same name as your function. This will overwrite your function name and if you put fire(3) below your import line it probably throws an error. Either change you fire function `fire(tf)` to  `fire_rocket(tf)` and change your `fire(3)` to `fire_rocket(3)` under the IF. 
Or add this on your import line (which you actually aren't even using!) and you can keep your fire function name as is:

```
from cbcnn import fire as Fire
```

**Edit after question was changed:**
Fix the IF I mentioned above and put fire(some number) in there.
The reason it fires is because when you import something from another program it runs the whole script. Because fire(3) is on there it will automatically call the function when you import it.
To avoid this you have to either:

- remove other parts from your cbcnn.py: `print` and `fire(3)`

Or

- put those parts in this IF statement to only run them when you actually run cbcnn.py yourself, and not by importing it:

  ```
  if __name__=='__main__':
      print(fire)
      fire(3)
  ```

Comment: Im sorry I didn't clarify I posted two scripts here. This first one is called cbcnn.py  "c-bot cannon". cbcnn.py script ends on fire(3). After that is the second script cbfd2.py "c-bot face detection 2". thats why, on the second portion, I "from cbcnn import fire".

Comment: I just edited my question, so that it is now easier to see that these are two separate scripts

Answer (score 0):

I already answer you in another post but, where you are putting:

```
cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
```

There you can put whatever you want, if you go into the for loop, it means you have detected a face. As you can see on the code you posted, in that case their a drawing a rectangle, but you can do anything there, the x,y,w and h are giving you the coordinates and size of the detected face.

Comment: I had to read over you guy's answers, many times before I could understand what you were trying to explain to me. 
I thank the both of you, SO MUCH, for looking at my scripts and taking the time to explain to me what I did wrong. Let me tell you, I was very upset when I logged on here for the first time, and asked my question, and was only greeted with criticism and negativity. 
I just now got it working the way that I want it to. I could not have figured it out, without you guys. Once again. Thank you very much. I will post the solution shortly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import io
import picamera
import cv2
import numpy
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
import time

#Create a memory stream so photos doesn't need to be saved in a file
stream = io.BytesIO()

#Get the picture (low resolution, so it should be quite fast)
#Here you can also specify other parameters (e.g.:rotate the image)
with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (320, 240)
    camera.vflip = True
    camera.capture(stream, format='jpeg')

#Convert the picture into a numpy array
buff = numpy.fromstring(stream.getvalue(), dtype=numpy.uint8)

#Now creates an OpenCV image
image = cv2.imdecode(buff, 1)

#Load a cascade file for detecting faces
face_cascade =    cv2.CascadeClassifier('/home/pi/cbot/faces.xml/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

#Convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Look for faces in the image using the loaded cascade file
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 5)

print "Found "+str(len(faces))+" face(s)"

#Draw a rectangle around every found face
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

    def init():
        gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
        gpio.setup(22, gpio.OUT)

    def fire(tf):
        init()
        gpio.output(22, True)
        time.sleep(tf)
        gpio.cleanup()

    print 'fire'
    fire(3)


#Save the result image
cv2.imwrite('result.jpg',image)
```

Comment: Since importing the "fire" command from a separate program, was causing the problem, I simply integrated the smaller program in to the larger one. And I put all the "fire" program stuff under the "for" stuff.

Comment: This is the wrong way of doing it... you shouldn't define functions in a for loop. You only need to define them once (usually right after imports). You can call your functions in a for loop (like you did with fire(3) ). Now about calling fire(3) in that for loop... This way if you have 5 people in the frame. it calls fire, then sleeps for 3 seconds and does the same until it fires 5 shots. This probably isn't what you want because by the time it fires the next shots, the frame should've already changed and those people might not even be in the other frames. you better use `if len(faces)>0`

Comment: Ah, yes. I understand what you are saying. I should move my definitions, up to the top, below my imports.
But this way, is actually working quite well.
Would I put the "if len(faces)>0" right below the cv2.rectangle(image......ect.   ?

Comment: Once again, I thank you very much, for taking the time to look at my scripts, and giving me advice. I know very little about  programming.

Comment: Defining functions in a for loop will just make your program slower (because it's just running unnecessary code every time the loop runs). It'll still work but it's completely wrong. And you can put that `if` before or after that for loop (it doesn't matter).